# How to minimize the Dashboard pane in a workspace by default when using multi-user mode

Tags: eclipse-che

I'm using Che 6.18.1 and 6.19.0 and I'd like to be able to provide a link to users to access a workspace without the Dashboard pane open, in order to maximize the useful screen real-estate for users. By Dashboard pane, I am talking about the area on the left side of the IDE with links for the Dashboard, Workspaces, Stacks, Factories, etc.

This is easy for me to do in Single-user mode, and I am able to use a link similar to http://HOST-IP:8080/che/WORKSPACE-NAME.

In multi-user mode the same link will run into a redirect loop between Keycloak and Che after logging in, which I assume is because the link is not valid in multi-user mode.

The default link to go to a particular workspace in multi-user mode seems to be http://HOST-IP:8080/dashboard/#/USER-NAME/WORKSPACE-NAME, which will always show the Dashboard pane. I've tried various combinations of this link to see if there is one with the pane minimized, but either it is not a valid link or it also ends up in a redirect loop. Taking a quick look at the Che API didn't seem to show any related settings in the preferences, etc.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The correct link will be:
`http://host:port/workspace-loader/USER-NAME/WORKSPACE-NAME`

BTW, Is there any particular reason to use Che 6.x ?
Che 7 is released you can check it out.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately I also get a redirect loop when using the above link, it seems to redirect to http://host:port/USER-NAME/WORKSPACE-NAME and then spins there.

Probably the only reason I haven't tried Che 7 yet is because I have some documentation / screenshots showing usage with Che 6, and I haven't checked to see if Che 7 looks any different with Theia.

Comment: To be honest I've tested that link with Che 7, because I don't have Che 6 installed.

Comment: No worries. I've taken a look at Che 7 and it seems like the pane gets minimized automatically. Thanks for helping!